# how to use web.xml file into spring boot application without extend WsConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-ws

I am using spring-boot to develop webservices, but I don't want to use `WsConfigurerAdapter` to define a WSDL and all, because I want to deploy my war into WAS7 and it does not support Servlet 3.0. So how would I add a `web.xml` configuration into my application.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot doesn't support Servlet 2.5 out of the box, however you can use [Spring Boot Legacy](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy) to get things working. Take a look at the [Google App Engine sample application](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae) for an example of how to use Spring Boot Legacy and `web.xml`.

You may also be interested in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1318) which is proposing to make Spring Boot Legacy an official part of Spring Boot.